# URL Title call on Page form MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, url

I created a blog with fields are **blog_title** and **blog_contents** these data are stored into mysql database and i want to display this blog post on **www.example.com/blog** page with specific **url blog_title**

eg: **www.example.com/blog/blog title**

Then particular title of the blog should be fetch form database
and displayed over the page.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to have a look at the "URL Rewrite".

Here's a link: [URL rewrite](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Some quick guidelines how I would do it:

Start from the url `www.example.com/blog.php?id=1`

You get the id from the url:

```
$blogId = $_GET['id']
```

Then your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs where id = $blogId
```

Build your page with the result of this query.

To get the url showed like you want: [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have o search for two things:

1. mod_rewrite / url rewriting, because on your server won't be a folder called /blog/this-is-my-blog-title (mod_rewrite will redirect that url to your e.g. index.php which does the rest)
2. you need that index.php which does the rest for you -> converting an url-blog-title into your real blog title in your database to fetch its content. The most easiest way is by using `urlencode()`, but then it will look really ugly. You need some script / code which converts whitespaces into hyphen (-) There are also some tutorials out there, just search for "seo friendly blog urls" for example.